# Pushing changes using Git CI/CD

Tags: git, cicd

Problem statment- I m trying to push changes from CI pipeline.

Current Implementation

```
git config --global user.email "mail_id@gmails.com"
git config --global user.name "bot"
git checkout -b try
git remote add -f b https://main.gitlab.com:ACCESSTOKEN@<GIT_URL>:<>/FOLDER/PROJECT.git
git remote update
git add .
git commit -m "Auto commit read_me files"
git push
git remote rm b
```

Error - I m getting gnutls_handshake() failed: An unexpected TLS packet was received.

When I try:

```
# Get global value
git config --global --get https.proxy
git config --global --get http.proxy
```

I get error Unsupported proxy syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Can you add the proxy steps for setting git proxy

### for global proxy

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port
```

### URL specific proxy

```
git config --global http.https://domain.com.proxy http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port
```

should result in the following git config

```
[http]
[http "https://<domain>.com"]
    proxy = http://proxyUsername:proxyPassword@proxy.server.com:port
```

NOTE: reffered from https://gist.github.com/evantoli/f8c23a37eb3558ab8765